# Why does hexokinase bond phosphate to the hydroxyl group on carbon-6 of glucose in glycolysis?

Tags: cell-biology, cellular-respiration, glucose

When glucose enters the cell, it is phosphorylated by the enzyme hexokinase.

**Why is this phosphorylation done at carbon-6? Why not at C-1 or C-2?**

In other words, why is glucose-6-phosphate being produced rather than a different isomer of phosphorylated glucose?

Comment: To be sure: You want to know, why glucose is phosphorylated at the carbon 6? Or do you want to know, why it is called carbon 6?

Comment: I want to this question? why glucose is phosphorylated at the carbon 6?

Comment: This is biochemically an interesting question, answer soon.

Comment: Weclome to Biology.SE! While you wait for @Chris to answer, you may want to check out the [proteopedia article on hexokinase](https://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Hexokinase) and the associated links. At very least that will make sure you have the background to understand an answer. ——— You may also wish to check out the [tour] and go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: What do you mean by “why”? Do you mean “what purpose does this serve”, or do you mean “how is this specificity accomplished”? At present you do not make this clear. I can answer either questions, but it is your job to formulate your question clearly. Please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all some nitpicking, but the actual phosphorylation happens not to the Carbon-6 but to the hydroxyl group bound to this carbon atom. The mechanism is a nucleophilic attack of the hydroxyl group on the terminal phosphoryl group of ATP. Schematically, this looks like this (image from [here](https://www.chem.uwec.edu/webpapers_f99/pages/Webpapers_F99/schneebm/Pages/reaction.html)):

[image]

The main question, why the reaction happens on this carbon atom can be answered rather simple (although the explanation is a bit longer): Because only this is openly available for a chemical reaction and the others are inside the hexokinase and thus shielded.

Hexokinase exists in two forms: One relaxed, open when no substrate is bound and one closed with a changed morphology when the enzyme has bound its substrate. This mechanism is called "[induced fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_catalysis#Induced_fit)" and a quite common motif in enzyme catalyzed reactions and brings together the active center of the enzyme, possible co-factors and the substrate and excludes interfering other actions.

In the example of the hexokinase, glucose is brought into close proximity to the terminal phosphoryl group of enzyme-bound ATP to enable the chemical reaction. Because all other potential hydroxy groups are shielded by the enzyme, only the group at the carbon-6 can be chemically active. For more details, see the references.

Schematically, this looks like this, with the open form to the left (the arrow indicates the binding site for glucose) and the closed form right (image from [here](https://pdb101.rcsb.org/motm/50)):

[image]

References

1. [The Structure and Mechanism of Hexokinase](https://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/The_Structure_and_Mechanism_of_Hexokinase)
2. [Mechanism of liver glucokinase.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00226892)

Comment: I think this answer is much more revealing, chris. Really thank you.As far as I understand, this is related to the way glucose binds to the enzyme.In other words, other hydroxyl groups are closed by the enzyme, so only the carboxyl group is exposed.I got it right, right?

Comment: @SpartanTroy No, only the hydroxyl group on C6 is available.

Comment: but if other hydroxyl groups are protected, why is it not protected on c6. Is this related to the enzyme's association with the substrat?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gZDHMQcgtQ. If this video is as shown; So that's about the enzyme's binding site to glucose and atp. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'll look into the video later today.

Comment: I'm sorry. I think you are knowledgeable. I'm asking because I don't fully understand.

Comment: Hey, be careful. I have no time right now to watch a video to see, what is said in there. And before I watched it, I am not going to say anything about the video. Answering here is voluntary, so **if** you want to piss me off, you will not get any answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106220/discussion-between-spartan-troy-and-chris).

Comment: @SpartanTroy There is nothing to discuss here right now. I have to work and will watch the video later. And then I will answer your question about it.

Comment: @SpartanTroy I'm not familiar with the particular biochemistry here, but just take a look at the diagram in Chris's answer: see the ring? There are 6 carbons, but only 5 of them are involved in the ring (an oxygen makes up the 6th ring element). The 6th is that "-CH2-" hanging off with an "-OH" attached to it. The other -OHs are directly attached on the ring: the geometry is different, so it seems obvious that an enzyme would be specific for a particular location.

Comment: @bryanKrause yes I have it see. Actually my question is a biochemistry question. But I want to understand.I think I should learn the enzyme and substrate relationship.

Comment: In yeast, galactose is phosphorylated at the C1 position and isomerized into glucose-1-phosphate, which is then converted to glucose-6-phosphate to go into glycolysis. Given that it's possible to phosphorylate the C1 position in galactose, which has similar steric considerations, your answer doesn't really answer why it's at C6 in glycolysis. I guess it impressed the questioner at least.